# Android can't show SD card photos in gallery

Tags: java, android, storage

I want to show both images located in the SD card "DCIM" folder and in the phone memory folder of the same name.

I manage to get the phone image directory by using:

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);`

But i can't seem to find the way to access the image folder located in the SD as well·

Any ideas?

Thanks for the attention. Jose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to solve it, wasn't a permission issue and `new File("/sdcard");` and `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());` where both giving me the device memory back.

Finally I try `new File("/storage").listFiles()` and I've got:

- storage/37B8-1908
- storage/emulated
- storage/self

Then It was just a mater of finding out witch directory was the SD and go look inside.

Answer (score 1):

Below is code for getting files from sdcard. you can get photos from that:

```
    File allfiles=new File("/sdcard");     // it can be /sdcard0 or /sdcard1
    File[] list=allfiles.listFiles();

    for(int i=0;i<list.length;i++)
    {
      Log.e("hidden path files.."+list[i].getAbsolutePath());
    }
```

you can also specify folder name followed by "/sdcard" for getting their photos or files.

Comment: ""/sdcard"" is devicespecific and will not work on every device. My Android 4.2 has "/sdcard0" and "/sdcard1" but no "/sdcard" . use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` instead.

Comment: @k3b it will also not work for all device as i already tried. you are also right. only "sdcard" not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following in android manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: If u have used it then try with this code:                                                     File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() ,"JCG Camera");

Comment: `"JCG Camera"` is quite device specific. It should be  `File mediaStorageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);` which is working for me